# C++ interfaces, inheritance, polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

Imagine this scenario:

- interface **I1**: `m1()`, implemented by class **C1**
- interface **I2**: `m2()`, implemented by class **C2**
- interface **I3**: `m3()`, implemented by class **C3**

And I want to define functions which take argument `arg`.

```
void f1(I1 arg) {
    use m1()
}

void f2([I1, I2] arg) {
    use m1() and m2()
}

void f3([I2, I3] arg) {
    use m2() and m3()
}
```

Then I want to define:

- a "union" interface **I123** which has all the methods, implemented by **C123**
- a "union" class **C123** which inherits implemented methods from existing classes **C1**, **C2**, **C3**.

Then I want to instantiate **C123** and use it with `f1`, `f2`, `f3`.

```
C123 obj;

f1(obj);
f2(obj);
f3(obj);
```

#### Questions

1. Is this possible in C++?
2. Is it possible without interfaces? Eg. function `f2` would take **[C1, C2]** instead of **[I1, I2]**.

---

#### The code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C1 {
protected:
  int i;
public:
  int getI() const { return i; }
  void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
};

class C2 {
protected:
  string s;
public:
  string getS() const { return s; }
  void setS(string s_) { s = s_; }
};

class C3 {
protected:
  float f;
public:
  float getF() const { return f; }
  void setF(float f_) { f = f_; }
};

class C23 : public C2, public C3 {};
class C123 : public C1, public C2, public C3 {};

void f3(C23 arg) {
  arg.setS(to_string(arg.getF()));
}


int main() {

  C123 obj;

  f3(obj);

  std::cout << obj.getS();
}
```

#### The error message

```
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:42:9: error: could not convert ‘obj’ from ‘C123’ to ‘C23’
   f3(obj);
```

Comment: "a "union" interface I123 which has all the methods, implemented by" implemented by what?

Comment: You can create a type for every combination that inherits from the appropriate interfaces (multiple inheritance is allowed). When this becomes unfeasible use templates instead to gain flexibility at the cost of error message clarity when you pass incompatible types.

Comment: What do you mean by "interface"? Do you have multiple abstract classes?

Comment: why do you put union in "" ? union has a well defined meaning in C++ or do you mean something different? If with "union" you mean that a class should implement methods of all three interfaces, then just inherit from all three

Comment: "Is it possible without interfaces?" is what possible? everything before is about interfaces, so it isnt clear what you want to do without

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry I haven't made it clear. The major issue is that **C123 cannot be converted to C23**. I guess it has something to do with memory layout. Also, I put union in "" because I don't want the actual union. I want all three -- C1,C2,C3 -- in one object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I123 inherits from I1,I2,I3. Those would be implemented as abstract classes since C++ doesn't have _interface_, as for example Java does.

Comment: To make your question more clear, I suggest that you show actual declarations for each class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added some code. It's simplified, but the important part is there.

Comment: Simplified code is good...as long as it's not simplified too much

Comment: Is this simplified too much? Get this working and I'll give you more code : )

Comment: We also need I1, I2, I3, and your attempts at I123 and C123.

Comment: Are the getters and setters the methods which are implemented from the interfaces?

Comment: You should give us enough code to recreate the exact error message you are asking about.

Comment: I see. You want proof that I actually tried it. Well, I did and it didn't work, so I ditched it, but let me put it back together.

Comment: What does "f2 would take [C1, C2] " mean? Can you write something that looks like c++? Do you mean function that takes two arguments, or 2 function overloads that take either `C1` or `C2`, or function that takes something that's convertible both to `C1` and `C2`?

Comment: @Pavel The last option. And I couldn't write it like C++ because I don't know _how to do it_ in C++. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice So I added "working" code, that is, code producing the error message.

Comment: @boofaz it's all easy to do, if you restrict that function f1, f2, f3 take your compound type C123, but the they won't work with just C1.

Comment: @Pavel That's what I'm trying to work around. Of course it would be easy with **C123** for all functions. But I want to convey that they only need to use the interface I1 or I1+I2 or I2+I3, etc.

Comment: @boofaz looks like virtual inheritance would work for you. See my proposed solution that use virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is this possible in C++?

Yes, it's possible to do that in C++.

### [Example solution using interfaces](https://ideone.com/e0yZQQ)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class I1 {
public:
    virtual int getI() const = 0;
    virtual void setI(int i) = 0;
};

class I2 {
public:
    virtual string getS() const = 0;
    virtual void setS(string s) = 0;
};

class I3 {
public:
    virtual float getF() const = 0;
    virtual void setF(float f) = 0;
};

class C1 : public I1 {
protected:
    int i;
public:
    int getI() const { return i; }
    void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
};

class C12 : public I1, public I2 {
protected:
    int i;
    string s;
public:
    int getI() const { return i; }
    void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
    string getS() const { return s; }
    void setS(string s_) { s = s_; }
};

class C123 : public I1, public I2, public I3 {
protected:
    int i;
    string s;
    float f;
public:
    int getI() const { return i; }
    void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
    string getS() const { return s; }
    void setS(string s_) { s = s_; }
    float getF() const { return f; }
    void setF(float f_) { f = f_; }
};

template<class T>
void f1(const T& c1)
{
    cout << "f1:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c1.getI() << endl;
}

template<class T>
void f2(const T& c12)
{
    cout << "f2:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c12.getI() << endl;
    cout << "  getS: " << c12.getS() << endl;
}

template<class T>
void f3(const T& c23)
{
    cout << "f3:\n";
    cout << "  getS: " << c23.getS() << endl;
    cout << "  getF: " << c23.getF() << endl;
}

void test()
{
    C1 c1;
    c1.setI(1);
    f1(c1);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C12 c12;
    c12.setI(12);
    c12.setS("str12");
    f1(c12);
    f2(c12);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C123 c123;
    c123.setI(123);
    c123.setF(1.23f);
    c123.setS("str123");
    f1(c123);
    f2(c123);
    f3(c123);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

> 2. Is it possible without interfaces? Eg. function f2 would take [C1, C2] instead of [I1, I2].

Yes, it's possible to do that without interfaces.

### [Solution using virtual inheritance (without using interfaces)](https://ideone.com/JpcNla):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C1 {
protected:
    int i;
public:
    int getI() const { return i; }
    void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
};

class C2 {
protected:
    string s;
public:
    string getS() const { return s; }
    void setS(string s_) { s = s_; }
};

class C3 {
protected:
    float f;
public:
    float getF() const { return f; }
    void setF(float f_) { f = f_; }
};

class C12 : public virtual C1, public virtual C2
{
};

class C23 : public virtual C2, public virtual C3
{
};

class C123 : public virtual C1, public virtual C12, public virtual C23
{
};


void f1(const C1& c1)
{
    cout << "f1:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c1.getI() << endl;
}

void f2(const C12& c12)
{
    cout << "f2:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c12.getI() << endl;
    cout << "  getS: " << c12.getS() << endl;
}

void f3(const C23& c23)
{
    cout << "f3:\n";
    cout << "  getS: " << c23.getS() << endl;
    cout << "  getF: " << c23.getF() << endl;
}

void test()
{
    C1 c1;
    c1.setI(1);
    f1(c1);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C12 c12;
    c12.setI(12);
    c12.setS("str12");
    f1(c12);
    f2(c12);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C123 c123;
    c123.setI(123);
    c123.setF(1.23f);
    c123.setS("str123");
    f1(c123);
    f2(c123);
    f3(c123);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

Some explanation. If you need your f2 to take only C1 and C2 (without C3) then it has to be separate type that inherits both on C1 and C2. Same goes for f3. Then, if you follow that logic and create classes `C12` and `C23` without using virtual inheritance then your C123 that should now inherit from both C12 and C23 will end up with multiple copies of C2 and when you call f2 and f3 you would get different values from `getS`. Virtual inheritance ensures that there is only one copy of a class in inheritance hierarchy.

> a "union" class C123 which inherits implemented methods from existing classes C1, C2, C3

### [Solution that use virtual inheritance and interfaces](https://ideone.com/ooI2XM)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class I1 {
public:
    virtual int getI() const = 0;
    virtual void setI(int i) = 0;
};

class I2 {
public:
    virtual string getS() const = 0;
    virtual void setS(string s) = 0;
};

class I3 {
public:
    virtual float getF() const = 0;
    virtual void setF(float f) = 0;
};

class I12 : virtual public I1, virtual public I2 {};
class I23 : virtual public I2, virtual public I3 {};
class I123 : virtual public I12, virtual public I23 {};

class C1 : virtual public I1 {
protected:
    int i;
public:
    int getI() const { return i; }
    void setI(int i_) { i = i_; }
};

class C2 : virtual public I2 {
protected:
    string s;
public:
    string getS() const { return s; }
    void setS(string s_) { s = s_; }
};

class C3 : virtual public I3 {
protected:
    float f;
public:
    float getF() const { return f; }
    void setF(float f_) { f = f_; }
};

class C12 : public I12, public C1, public C2 {};
class C123 : public I123, public C1, public C2, public C3 {};

void f1(const I1& c1)
{
    cout << "f1:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c1.getI() << endl;
}

void f2(const I12& c12)
{
    cout << "f2:\n";
    cout << "  getI: " << c12.getI() << endl;
    cout << "  getS: " << c12.getS() << endl;
}

void f3(const I123& c23)
{
    cout << "f3:\n";
    cout << "  getS: " << c23.getS() << endl;
    cout << "  getF: " << c23.getF() << endl;
}

void test()
{
    C1 c1;
    c1.setI(1);
    f1(c1);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C12 c12;
    c12.setI(12);
    c12.setS("str12");
    f1(c12);
    f2(c12);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;

    C123 c123;
    c123.setI(123);
    c123.setF(1.23f);
    c123.setS("str123");
    f1(c123);
    f2(c123);
    f3(c123);

    cout << "\n===== " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

All solutions should produce this output:

```
f1:
  getI: 1

=====
f1:
  getI: 12
f2:
  getI: 12
  getS: str12

=====
f1:
  getI: 123
f2:
  getI: 123
  getS: str123
f3:
  getS: str123
  getF: 1.23

=====
```

Comment: Thanks. That basically answers my question number 2. Don't know why the downvote.

Comment: @boofaz there is probably a way to make something using virtual interfaces, but for your specific requirements virtual inheritance fits the most IMO.

Comment: @boofaz I added solution that uses interfaces without virtual inheritance.

Comment: Like DaveFar in his answer, you reimplement the methods `getI`,`setI`, etc. instead of inheriting them. The reason to use inheritance is that you don't have to reimplement already implemented methods.

Comment: @boofaz for that you would need to use virtual inheritance of interfaces. It will effectively become more complicated solution that solves your second question.

Comment: I added one more solution that implements requirement of "a "union" class C123 which inherits implemented methods from existing classes C1, C2, C3". Perhaps some stuff there could be cleaned up, as you see virtual inheritance without interfaces looks cleanest. If you really need interfaces then you need to use both.

Comment: That answers my first question then. I don't really _need_ interfaces, but this might come in handy. Basically what I wanted was sort of "duck typing" where each function `f1`, `f2`, `f3` would explicitly declare that it only uses `getS`/`setS` and `getI`/`setI`, etc. and if the argument satisfies that, it's a valid argument.

Comment: The template portion is a solution, templates are duck-typed, so you immediately support any type implementing both `m1()` and `m2()` (whether or not interfaces are used).  Your virtual inheritance *doesn't* work, because now there's a function which needs to use members from `C1` and `C3` and `C123` should be compatible, but it isn't.  You need duck-typing here to avoid the combinatorial explosion of base classes, which means you need templates.

Comment: @boofaz: Templates are duck-typed, the template solution Pavel presented for interfaces works equally well with no inheritance at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, second solution doesn't really address what was asked. 3rd solution addresses that. In place of templates there could as well be multiple overloads instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible via pure abstract classes and multiple inheritance. Since there are no conflicts between `I1`, `I2`, and `I3`, multiple inheritance does not cause any problems.

Exemplary implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class I1 {
public:
    virtual void m1() = 0;
    virtual ~I1(){};
};

class C1 : public I1 {
public:
    void m1() override {
        std::cout << "m1() of a C1" << std::endl;
    }
    ~C1(){};
};

class I2 {
public:
    virtual void m2() = 0;
    virtual ~I2(){};
};

class C2 : public I2 {
public:
    void m2() override {
        std::cout << "m2() of a C2" << std::endl;
    }
    ~C2(){};
};

class I3 {
public:
    virtual void m3() = 0;
    virtual ~I3(){};
};

class C3 : public I3 {
public:
    void m3() override {
        std::cout << "m3() of a C3" << std::endl;
    }
    ~C3(){};
};

class I12 : public I1, public I2 {
public:
    virtual ~I12(){};
};

class I23 : public I2, public I3 {
public:
    virtual ~I23(){};
};

class I123 : public I12, public I23 {
public:
    virtual ~I123(){};
};

class C123 : public I123 {
public:
    void m1() override {
        std::cout << "m1() of a C123" << std::endl;
    }
    void m2() override {
        std::cout << "m2() of a C123" << std::endl;
    }
    void m3() override {
        std::cout << "m3() of a C123" << std::endl;
    }
    ~C123(){};
};

void f1(I1 &arg) {
    std::cout << "f1():" << std::endl;
    arg.m1();
}

void f2(I12 &arg) {
    std::cout << "f2():" << std::endl;
    arg.m1();
    arg.m2();
}

void f3(I23 &arg) {
    std::cout << "f3():" << std::endl;
    arg.m2();
    arg.m3();
}

int main() {
    C123 object;
    f1(object);
    f2(object);
    f3(object);
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
f1():
m1() of a C123
f2():
m1() of a C123
m2() of a C123
f3():
m2() of a C123
m3() of a C123
```

This shows that C++ offers multiple inheritance that fulfills your requirements. However, I suggest you read up [Effective C++ Item 40](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876): Use multiple inheritance judiciously. The chapter suggests to use virtual base classes only when necessary. So when you do have a "deadly MI diamond" with conflicts, use all the above pure virtual classes as virtual base classes (i.e. all classes that immediately inherit from it do via `: virtual public ....`. The cost is lower performance and more complex initialization rules.

---

Update:

If you want to inherit the implementation of C1, C2 and C3 in C123 (note that implementation inheritance is often bad design), you do the following:

- use `I1`, `I2`, `I3`, `I12`, `I23`, `I123` as virtual base classes, and
- implement `class C123 : virtual public I123, public C1, public C2, public C3` without reimplementing `m1()`, `m2()`, and `m3()`.

The resulting output is

```
f1():
m1() of a C1
f2():
m1() of a C1
m2() of a C2
f3():
m2() of a C2
m3() of a C3
```

Comment: That's good. But what about `I123` being converted to `I23`? All my attempts so far were unsuccessful -- GCC says "Cannot convert from `C123` to `I23`".

Comment: I have added an implementation.

Comment: `I123` contains 2 copies of `I2` which it should not have.

Comment: 2 copies of I2 do not cause a conflict. Whenever you get a conflict, use virtual base classes (or better, an alternative to multiple inheritance).

Comment: One of the requirements was to not reimplement `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, but inherit them from C1, C2, C3. This code doesn't do that, and after some modifications (making C123 inherit public from C1,C2,C3), I get `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘I12&’ from expression of type ‘C123’`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to inherit from C1, C2, C3. I am updated my answer now accordingly (at the bottom under "update").

Comment: @user54264611634646244: Do declare destructors virtual in polymorphic base classes (Effective C++ Item 7).

Comment: @DaveFar Don't blindly follow everything He-Man writes.

Comment: It is not necessary for the OP's question. There are no virtual functions in the OP's code @tobi303. [Check what Stroustrup has to say about this](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual-dtor), **"So when should I declare a destructor virtual? Whenever the class has at least one virtual function."**

Comment: There are no virtual functions because I excluded them for brevity, but of course there would be virtual functions in `I1`,`I2`,`I3`. Why else would I want an interface if it didn't have any functions?

Comment: No worries, boofaz: you did mention the functions m1() to m3() in your interfaces I1 to I3.

Answer (score 0):

C++ typing is distinct from Java's typing, so it is often easier to approach problems by re-evaluating your needs. There are two different ways to derive new objects using old behaviour, and it's really important to understand the benefits to each one.

**Inheritance** is the first, where you basically copy the functionality of the old object, then add more to it. This becomes a problem when you have many different parent objects all implementing the same functionality. The second is **composition**, where you put many objects together inside the new object. The new object then can 'choose' which behaviours to use, often removing the ambiguity of multiple-inheritance. It comes at the cost that you must define the behaviour because the compiler cannot reason so deeply about your intended behaviour.

In your situation, I read that you have 3 different objects which behave differently, and you need to *compose* (rather than *inherit*) their behaviour. You describe that you need to call `m()` for any `I#` included in the composed object; this is quite easy.

Define a wrapper object, and conditionally call the `m` function provided by each of the interfaces:

```
class Wrapper {
    I1 slot1;
    I2 slot2;
    I3 slot3;

    Wrapper(i1 = I1.default(), i2 = I2.default(), i3 = I3.default()) {
        slot1 = i1;
        slot2 = i2;
        slot3 = i3;
    }

    void foo() {
        // The default instances don't do anything on m()
        slot1::m();
        slot2::m();
        slot3::m();
    }

}
```

There is no doubt a lot of room for improvement and optimization, but this is the general idea.

Looking at your example code, you may want to look at the concept of a `Logger` for debugging. Many languages use them and you 'subscribe' `cout/cerr` to different logger feeds provided by different sections of your program. For example you might have a logger for physics, and another one for graphics.

They seem very similar to your selective outputting of different data types available in an object.

Comment: Defaults are terrible and you should feel bad, also you forgot to use `::` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Puppy Yeah, definitely not ideal. I'm no template wizard, so I focused mostly on the conceptual side of things. Thanks for catching my error.